# Нужно поменять формат даты в SQL через запрос результат

Tags: sql, база-данных

Не получается изменить формат даты и времени в отчете .
Сейчас при получение ответа отчета формат даты и времени 2024-03-18, а необходимо поменять на 20240318 без знака ‘/’

Вот скрипт select substr (card, 1, 8) as bin, term_id, case when card_type in ('05', '51') then 'VISA' end as card_type, '1'

но тут не преобразуются значения дат он сам в формате yyyy/dd/mm
Использую СУБД ORACL PLSQL 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каким запросом выбираются данные? Покажите, как сейчас преобразуются значения дат. Так же у вас в примере разделитель '-'(тире), хотя в вопросе просите без знака '/'.

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию. У каждой СУБД - свои средства (функции) для форматирования даты.

Comment: Вот скрипт 

select substr (card, 1, 8) as bin, term_id, case when card_type in ('05', '51') then 'VISA' end as card_type, '1' 

но тут не преобразуются значения дат он сам в формате yyyy/dd/mm 

Использую СУБД ORACL PLSQL 12

Comment: Вот скрипт select substr (card, 1, 8) as bin, term_id, case when card_type in ('05', '51') then 'VISA' end as card_type, '1' но тут не преобразуются значения дат он сам в формате yyyy/dd/mm Использую СУБД ORACL PLSQL 1

Comment: Где в этом скрипте работа с датой?

Comment: Cмотрите тут скрипт для получение базы покупки с временем но в столбце времени получаю в формате 2024/27/03 надо просто что бы результат был без '/' 20242703  приклеплю фото

Comment: У вас на фото и в описании формат дат расходится. Если предположить, что то что заявлено имеет тип даты, то возможно поможет: `to_char(tr_date, 'YYYYMMDD')`

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш отчет берется из sql запроса и нет необходимости вносить изменения в бд, то для  `select` можете использовать `replace(tr_date, '/', '')`